# JSON to NSDictionary. Shouldn't be this hard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am getting an error* when I'm putting JSON data into an NSDictionary. The error I am receiving is because the key is not being recognised.

*The error[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d26cd0

JSON string output looks like this:

```
[{"Username":"TestUsername"}]
```

The code I am using:

```
if(error == nil)
{
   NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSLog(@"%@",text);

   NSError *error;
   NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

   //Fails when using NSDictionary instead of NSArray
   NSLog(@"json: %@", [json objectForKey:@"Username"]);

   //NSLog(@"json: %@", json[0]);
}
```

When I use NSArray, this is the output:

```
{
    Username = Elder;
}
```

Comment: Here `json` is `NSArray` not `NSDictionary`. So `[json objectForKey:@"Username"]` will crash. So use `[json[0] objectForKey:@"Username"]` instead and change json to `NSArray *json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JSON` is `Array` its not `Dictionary`.  In json array first object is dictionary.

Corrected your code:

```
if(error == nil)
{
   NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSLog(@"%@",text);

   NSError *error;
   NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

   //Fails when using NSDictionary instead of NSArray
   NSLog(@"json: %@", [json[0] objectForKey:@"Username"]);

   //NSLog(@"json: %@", json[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to

```
 NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

 //Check the array count if required, if count is 0, jsonArray[0] crashes
 NSString *userName = [jsonArray[0] objectForKey:@"Username"];

 NSLog(@"json: %@", userName);
```

In your code `JSONObjectWithData:` returns a `NSArray` not `NSDictionary`. So `objectForKey:` on `NSArray` cause crash.